# Multiple If Else statements and how to control them

Tags: vb.net

In my web application I have defined a `Regex`, `Match` and `str`. So the `Regex` will be used to compare other strings with `str` and the `Match` to identify any matches found in the `textboxes`. In my code I have 3 strings defined as `matches` to be compared with `str`. A connection to the database is also defined. The following code shows the definitions:

```
    Dim r As Regex = New Regex(str2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim m1 As Match = r.Match(txt1.Text.ToString)
    Dim m2 As Match = r.Match(txt2.Text.ToString)
    Dim m3 As Match = r.Match(txt3.Text.ToString)
    Dim myconn As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
```

The part I am facing problems with is that I have many `if else` statements and I cannot determine a way to control them appropriately as follows:

```
If (m1.Success) AND (m2.Success) AND (m3.Success) Then

     Try
          myconn.Open()
          Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("Update Std SET Title = @param ", myconn)
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", Data.SqlDbType.Bit).Value = bit_True
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
          cmd.Dispose()
          myconn.Close()
     Catch ex As Exception
          Response.Write(ex)
          End Try

ElseIf (m2.Success) Then
     Try
          myconn.Open()
          Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("Update Teacher SET In_name = @param ", myconn)
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", Data.SqlDbType.Bit).Value = bit_True
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
          cmd.Dispose()
          myconn.Close()
     Catch ex As Exception
          Response.Write(ex)
          End Try

ElseIf (m3.Success) Then
     Try
          myconn.Open()
          Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("Update Std SET std_name = @param ", myconn)
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", Data.SqlDbType.Bit).Value = bit_True
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
          cmd.Dispose()
          myconn.Close()
     Catch ex As Exception
          Response.Write(ex)
          End Try
     End If
```

What I am expecting out of the code is to:

1. Check the first condition `m1.success` if `true` then execute the **first** `Try` block otherwise if `False` ignore all `Try` blocks AND move to the next condition (m2), then
2. Check the second condition `m2.success` if `true` then execute the **second** `Try` block, otherwise if `False` ignore all `Try` blocks AND move to the next condition (m3), then
3. Same goes for `m3.Success`

So this implies that the first `Try` block relates to the first `if statement` `(m1.Success)` and should be executed only if the condition (m1) is true. Same goes for m2 and m3. In this way I would be have a dynamic control upon the statements. So

`m1` = execute first `Try` block.

`m2` = execute second `Try` block.

`m3` = execute third `Try` block.

Any condition which returns `False` will be ignored along with its `Try` block.

Any suggestions or thoughts on how to have a dynamic control over those conditions ?

Comment: Your code checks for all 3 successes around the first query, but the description only mentions 1. What do you want to do if multiple matches succeed?

Comment: @hans Kesting, that is my requirement, is to check all three conditions and execute their `Try` block if any return `True`. So execute only the ones that return `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just this?

```
If (m1.Success) Then

    '[...]

End If
If (m2.Success) Then

    '[...]

End If
If (m3.Success) Then

    '[...]

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Enum as a Flag to control which of the blocks will execute by checking them with AND statements and the enum value will be a result of the successes of the regex.

Another optimization would be to open/close the connection before/after the whole If so that you boost performance a bit.

Answer (score 0):

it is a web application, so I assume you have put the database connections in a connection pool or a connection manager.

Define a abstract class that does the following

1. match a certain reg pattern (this should be overridden in its sub classes)
2. when a match occur, do the following
   2.1. grab a database connection from the pool
   2.2. run certain queries against the datbase
   2.3. return the database connection to the pool
3. return to the main logic

You can create as many pattern/logic as you need in sub classes, and put their instances in a collection (array or list). Upon receiving a user request, run through all instances and let them do their matching and database querying.